# How to assess codeigniter helpers from external library

Tags: codeigniter

please help me with the below code. I'm trying to assess base_url helper from Mylib(external library)

```
Class Mylib{
    public function url() {
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('url');
        return base_url();
    }
}
```

Comment: any errors or any outputs ??

Comment: No output, while trying to assess it from the controller.

Comment: echo it and see

Comment: still blank, can't get any thing

Comment: where is this placed ?

Comment: The above is place in the library folder(application/library/Mylib.php), I load the library from controller and try to assess the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its works fine. Check this.

```
class Mylib {

    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function url(){
        this->CI->load->helper('url');
        redirect();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this work what if the method is to be static(I'm using static method).